# use custom ordinal enum inside @embedded in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a composite key as follows

```
@Embeddable
public class TableAPrimary implements  Serializable{

   private Course course;
   private int tableId;  
}
```

> Course is an enum here

However the id value I have in database is not mapped to ordinal in enumeration.

For eg. I have

```
enum Course{

   HISTORY(20), MATHS(100);

   private Course(int courseId) {
        id = courseId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
     private static final Map<Integer, Course> lookup = new HashMap<Integer, Course>();

    static {
        for (Course courseId : Course.values()) {
            lookup.put(courseId.getId(), courseId);
        }
    }
    public static Course getById(int id) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        Course courseId = lookup.get(id);

        if (courseId == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No course enum exists for Id " + id);
        }

        return courseId;
    }
}
```

Could you please help me set the correct `enum` based on the `custom id` from database inside `@embedded`

Comment: So what it is database instead of ordinal? You tried to explicit add @Enumerated?

Comment: database has values such as 20,100 etc for each row respectfully. I tried adding @Enumerated but still cannot convert to correct enum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't allow that, first you cannot define custom ordinal in java. From the javadocs for `ordinal()`;

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its
>   enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of
>   zero).

Secondly, from hibernate documentation,

> Hibernate Annotations support out of the box enum type mapping either
>   into a ordinal column (saving the enum ordinal) or a string based
>   column (saving the enum string representation): the persistence
>   representation, defaulted to ordinal, can be overridden through the
>   @Enumerated annotation as shown in the note property example.

Also, you can't name string enum with number so you have no use from `name()` neither.
Hibernate uses `ordinal or name` for mapping enums and both are `final` methods, so there is no flexibility with enums.

Maybe there are some workarounds but I'll bet they don't use `@Enumerated`. 
What you can do is to update database values, all 20=>0 and 100=>1, and then it'll work with ordinal or update all 20=>HISTORY and 100=>MATH, and then it'll work with name. (`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`)

Hope I'm wrong.